# How to convert upper case letters to lower case

Tags: python

I have a script which reads the input and than lists it, however i want it to convert upper case letters to lower case, how can i do that?

this is what i got

```
 for words in text.readlines():
    sentence = [w.strip(',.') for w in line.split() if w.strip(',.')]
    list.append(sentence)
```

Comment: if you found the `strip` and `split` methods of `str`, how hard can it be to search for `upper` and `lower`?

Comment: please type these things into google before coming here, python docs is hit 1 and has the correct answer.
For the record the answer is `thestring.lower()`

Answer (score 133):

You can find more methods and functions related to Python strings in section [5.6.1. String Methods](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) of the documentation.

```
w.strip(',.').lower()
```

Answer (score 29):

`str.lower()` converts all cased characters to lowercase.

Answer (score 5):

To convert a string to lower case in Python, use something like this.

```
list.append(sentence.lower())
```

I found this in the first result after searching for "python upper to lower case".