# My spelling checker cannot compare words correctly

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, full-text-search, pygame, linear-search

For a programming lab my assignment is to write a program that checks the spelling of a word. I am doing this all on my own so this is basically my last resort.The program should work like this: iterate through all lines of the document you want to check.If a word is not in the dictionary, print the word and the line where you found it.

I have to use a dictionary file in which all words are capitalized.The file that I'm checking for correct spelling
isn't. So somewhere I have to capitalize the words, but I cannot figure out where. Every time I run this code it just print every line in the AliceInWonderLand200.txt.

### My code:

```
import re
def split_line(line):
    return re.findall('[A-Za-z]+9(?:\'[A-Za-z]+)',line)

file = open("dictionary.txt")
dictionary = []
for line in file:
    line = line.strip()
    dictionary.append(line)
file.close()
print("----Linear search-----")
file2 = open("AliceInWonderLand200.txt")
i = 0
for line in file2:
    words = []
    words.append(split_line(line))
    for word in line:
        i+= 1
        word = word.upper()
        if word not in dictionary:
            print("Line ",i,": probably misspelled: ", word)
file.close()
```

### What I have tried:

I have tried to use words.append(split_line(line.upper()),but that didn't work. I have tried to assign word to word.upper(), that didn't work either. Every time when I run this code it just prints every line in the AliceInWonderLand200.txt.

I have looked everywhere to find a satisfying answer. I have found the same question here on stackoverflow, but I didn't really understand the answer [Python Spell Checker Linear Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17491069/python-spell-checker-linear-search)

### edit

I have added the task and the output that I should have to make it easier for you guys.

### What my output should be:

```
--- Linear Search ---
Line 3  possible misspelled word: Lewis
Line 3  possible misspelled word: Carroll
Line 46  possible misspelled word: labelled
Line 46  possible misspelled word: MARMALADE
Line 58  possible misspelled word: centre
Line 59  possible misspelled word: learnt
Line 69  possible misspelled word: Antipathies
Line 73  possible misspelled word: curtsey
Line 73  possible misspelled word: CURTSEYING
Line 79  possible misspelled word: Dinah'll
Line 80  possible misspelled word: Dinah
Line 81  possible misspelled word: Dinah
Line 89  possible misspelled word: Dinah
Line 89  possible misspelled word: Dinah
Line 149  possible misspelled word: flavour
Line 150  possible misspelled word: toffee
Line 186  possible misspelled word: croquet
```

the task:
http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=lab_spell_check

Comment: Does `dictionary.txt` contain one word per line? Also, you want `word.title()` to capitalize only the first letter of the word

Comment: Yes it does contain on word per line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're better off using a `set` to hold your dictionary words, for better lookup speeds. Also, it would help to lowercase all the words in your dictionary to make comparisons more uniform.

```
with open('dictionary.txt') as infile:
    dictionary = {line.strip().lower() for line in infile}

print("----Linear search-----")
with open('AliceInWonderLand200.txt') as infile:
    for i,line in enumerate(infile, 1):
        line = line.strip()
        words = split_line(line) # your split_line function
        for word in words:
            if word.lower() not in dictionary:
                print("Line ", i, ": probably misspelled: ", word)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @Learner No sweat! We should probably clean up the comments, though (delete the ones that are no longer relevant)

Answer (score 0):

You can lowercase the words in the dictionary:

```
for line in file:
    line = line.strip().lower()
    dictionary.append(line)
```

and lowercase the word that you are checking for:

```
for word in line:
    i += 1
    word = word.lower()
    ...
```

Comment: I have tried it, but it still prints all lines. My document which I need to check contains both lower() and upper() characters. Now I see you have added more!

Comment: which new words appeared?

Comment: It was my split_line function that didn't work very well. There was nothing wrong with your suggestion.